# Django how to preserve order when querying OneToMany relations?

Tags: django

Two models (A report may contain many screenshots):

```
class Report(models.Model):
    ...

class Screenshot(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, related_name='screenshots', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="screenshots/%Y/")
    order = models.IntegerField()

    class meta:
        ordering = ['order'] # output the correct order
```

When querying all reports and there associated screenshots:

```
reports = Report.objects.all()
for r in reports:
    screenshots = r.screenshots.all()
    for s in screenshots:
        print s.order  # output is out of order like 4,1,2,3
```

The order of the screenshots are not preserved.

Is there a better way to make queries like this but preserves OneToMany relations' order?

Comment: Two things: class meta should be class Meta (you have a typo), second try not to name the column 'order', find a better name for that...

Comment: Can you check if the PK of `Screenshot` is in order? Alternatively, you could try to make `order` the model's PK. You could also use `order_by()` (reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)) to force sorting.

Comment: @MujGabriel Thanks for pointing out the typo. That was the issue.